# Neo4j: Converting string to datetime

Tags: datetime, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have my data loaded on Neo4j instance where, for each node, I recorded the temporal information in a property key (.time) following the format:

> YYYY-MM-DD

example: `time: 1937-01-01`

These are all strings, that I would like to convert into datetime as to use them in Neo4j Bloom and various time-based queries. I tried to use the following formula (as well as various variations of it):

```
MATCH (p:Image)
WHERE p.time IS NOT NULL
SET p.time = datetime({ epochMillis: apoc.date.parse(p.time, 's', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') })
```

without success. I always get the error

```
Failed to invoke function `apoc.date.parse`: Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1891-01-01"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to transform date as string to datetime ?

I read some previous posts on the subject but I couldn't find a satisfying answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data format and the format you specified in the `apoc` function don't match. Also, you might wanna parse milliseconds, rather than seconds, since you are using `epochMillis` field.

Try this:

```
MATCH (p:Image)
WHERE p.time IS NOT NULL AND p.time <> ""
SET p.time = datetime({ epochMillis: apoc.date.parse(p.time + " 00:00:00", 'ms', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') })
```

Ok, then for your error you will have to use your previous format, and convert your date into your format. The error basically meant that millisecond component is not present.

Comment: Ok that make sense..However, I get the following error:
`Neo.ClientError.Statement.ArgumentError Cannot construct date time from: NO_VALUE`. No idea why, as the date are standardize before loading and always present

Comment: thanks, but I get another error this time `Failed to invoke function `apoc.date.parse`: Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " 00:00:00"`. I tried also with `(p.time + "T00:00:00", "ms", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")` but I get the same error

Comment: Seems like you have empty strings in p.time

Comment: just checking exactly that, I realised I have two empty string

Comment: updated the answer to ignore empty time fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `date()` if you have only date part without time. You can call `date('2015-07-21')` directly.

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/#functions-date-create-string